# Does Reaper contest the point in his Wraith-form?

Tags: overwatch

We just had a game where an enemy D.Va used her ult with six of us attackers on the point.  Five of us ran away, while our Reaper stayed on the point using Wraith form.  The Reaper never left the point *(I have it on video, I triple-checked)*, but we lost anyways.

Everything I've read online suggests a Reaper in Wraith form can hold the point.  Is this incorrect?  Or has it changed at some point?  Or was this just a bug?

Comment: From my own experience, Reaper can contest a point, but can never actually take the point in his Wraith form. I know it doesn't answer your question. I still have some questions myself about how his Wraith form works with points and I "main" him

Comment: Reaper's wraith form along with Mei's self-freeze both should contest points if they are on them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes, but with a caveat.**

Reaper (and Mei, to cover both immunities) can both *contest* points or payloads owned by the enemy. This is easily seen in most games, so I don't feel proof is necessary.

The caveat here, is that they ***cannot*** capture points. I did not test payloads, but I can safely assume the same logic is behind it.

[Reaper using Wraith form on an unconstested (neutral) point.](http://plays.tv/video/579a7f3ceb58f7751d/reaper-wraith-on-point)

[Mei using Ice Block on an uncontested (neutral) point.](http://plays.tv/video/579a7f995661c82fa4/mei-ice-block-on-point)

If necessary, I can also knock up some video evidence of trying to capture an enemy point while not contested, but I don't think there will be a difference.

==EDIT==

As per Blue-Raja's comment, I did further testing on the nature of Overtime and contesting versus capping. My results were fully in-line with the above evidence- both can contest a point and extend Overtime during the duration of their in-vulnerabilities, but neither can capture a point or move a cart in that time.

Comment: So a Reaper on a point in overtime will hold the point when you're on defenders, but not when you're on attackers?  That's idiotic!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft A Reaper could hold the point during overtime on either side, but if he was attacking, he could not increase the capture % while in Wraith Form.

Comment: Are you sure?  Did you test that?  That conflicts with my experience.

Comment: I didn't specifically test Overtime, but I can do tonight and post another video

Comment: I've seen mei lose the point during overtime while in ice block on numbani

Comment: Then she wasn't on the point, or jumped on too late. A Cryostatis'd Mei *will* contest provided there is something there to be constested.

Answer (score 3):

While not appearing to be [the greatest of sources](http://overwatch.wikia.com/wiki/Wraith_Form), it does appear that Reaper can contest points while in Wraith Form. It is not clear if he can capture points while using this ability, but I believe he can still move payloads while in Wraith Form.

As far as I can tell from sources and experience with the game, Mei can also contest a point while in her invulnerable Ice Form as well.

Comment: Mei can capture points while in Cryostasis. She can also stop or move payloads in it. Reaper- I'm not certain of as I play less of him than Mei, but I can't imagine there would be different rules. I can do some testing later if I remember.

Comment: I was mistaken regarding Mei. Posted an answer clarifying the capturing points, but from my experience, the Overwatch wiki doesn't contain *that much* disinformation. It's also a community page, so there's nothing stopping anyone from fixing false information :)

Answer (score -5):

(Yeah characters can't contest while invulnerable. In the case of Reaper I'm sure that it won't contest if he entered the point while being in wraith form. I suppose that he will stop contesting if he uses wraith form while on the point.) 
Surely a bug.

Comment: And how exactly are you sure of this? Because you've answered with false information, and without sourcing. If you can find a source that tells us that Reaper and Mei can't contest while invulnerable, then I'll take back what I've said.

Comment: Actually I tested it about 3 weeks ago. May be kinda outdated or could be a bug corrected.

Comment: Yes, and I've been testing it since game launch, and I can confirm that both Reaper and Mei can contest while invulnerable.

Comment: My bad then. I edit to let that appear.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is intended behavior...

Comment: This should be trivial to test both questions alone in a hybrid map. I'm not aware of any suggestion that map objectives function differently in custom games versus in matchmaking.